# Retain STOMP session in Spring Boot MVC app

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, activemq-artemis, stomp

I have a Spring Boot MVC app that connects to an external ActiveMQ Artemis server. The app has a notification module that receives notifications from certain services when some events occur. Since this is multi-page app every time an user opens a page a new STOMP connection is created.

Is there a way to retain the session and a reuse it on all pages? This is the client's code that is used to connect.

```js
// Start listening to incoming notifications.
function startListening() {

    const importSocket = new SockJS("/stomp/user");
    const notificationStompClient = Stomp.over(importSocket);

    notificationStompClient.connect({}, (frame) => {
        console.log('Connected to ' + frame);
        subscribeToNotifications(notificationStompClient);
    }, (message) => {
        console.log(message);
        if (message instanceof Object) {
            const body = JSON.parse(message.body);
            if (body.statusCode ===  401) retryNotificationListener = false;
        } else if (message.includes('Whoops! Lost connection to') && retryNotificationListener)
            setTimeout(() => startListening(), 15000);
    });
}
```